# AngularJs edit only undefined or null field in a Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, input

I need to make editable with a text input only the undefined field from an ng-repeat. For example this is a possible object:

```
{
  "name": "Alex",
  "number": "12547",
  "visible": true,
  "text": undefined
}
```

I need to fill the `undefined` field. But the others not! What's the problem? If i write something like that:

```
<span ng-if="dataValue.text != undefined">
   {{dataValue.text}}
</span>
<input type="text" ng-if="dataValue.text == undefined" ng-model="dataValue.text" />
```

When i type the first letter the input disappears because it finds that it's not undfined anymore! And I can't edit it! Is there any fast way to do it? Summary, I need to keep not editable the fields that aren't undefined, but I need to edit the fields undefined.
I can't use the one-time-binding in this case. Thanks

The code is inside a table. The example shows a `<td></td>` part which inside there are the `<span>` and the `<input>`

Comment: You can use the one-time binding syntax and do `ng-if="::dataValue.text == undefined"`, I think anyway.

Comment: I tried, but I can't do it because the table has a pagination and changing the page it keeps the input in the same place of the previous page

Comment: how about keeping a copy and using that to show/hide instead of actual object itself?

Comment: @tanmay should be a way. But at the end I have to use the original object because I have to send that data to the server

Comment: @End.Game sure, I am saying use a copy for show/hide stuff.. your models are from original object itself.. so there should not be issue with sending it to server..

Answer (score 2):

You can handle as this example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);

            app.controller("MainCtrl", MainCtrl)
            MainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
            function MainCtrl($scope) {
                $scope.dataValue = { "name": "Alex", "number": "12547", "visible": true, "text": undefined };
                $scope.changedataValue = function () {
                    $scope.dataValue.text = event.target.value;
                }
            }


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <span ng-if="dataValue.text != null">{{dataValue.text}}
            </span>
            <input ng-blur="changedataValue()" type="text" ng-if="dataValue.text == null" />
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works in part. I mean, It's ok at the beginning but I can't edit it again

Answer (score 1):

you can call a function in `ng-blur` directive and assign the model to a separate variable.

```
<input type="text" ng-if="dataValue.text == undefined" ng-model="dataValue.sampleText" ng-blur="callFunc(dataValue)" />
```

in the controller call the function

```
$scope.callFunc = function(dataValue){
   if(dataValue.sampleText && dataValue.sampleText !== ''){
        dataValue.text = dataValue.sampleText
   }
}
```

Comment: Now I try this way

Comment: Almost. It's a good way to avoid that the input disappears when you are writing in it. But of course when you click outside it disappears and I can't edit it anymore!

Comment: @End.Game then you can use the `ng-click` as an alternative and pass event as another parameter. Then check if the key you press is `enter` then hide the input

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-init to init a value for disabling the field. If the value is not `null` or `undefined` immediately disable it. Otherwise on blur check it again and if you typed something disable it, otherwise keep it enabled:

```
<input type="text" ng-init="dataValue.toDisable = !(dataValue.text == null)" ng-disabled="dataValue.toDisable" ng-model="dataValue.text" ng-blur="dataValue.toDisable = !(dataValue.text == null);"  />
```

See the double equal. This will disable all the input where text is null or undefined, because `null == undefined`.

Comment: What is exactly dataValue.toDisable ?

Comment: a new attribute created runtime in order to disable or not inputs

Comment: Hmm.. the closer answer is the sachila ranawaka'answer I think. I mean, in that way I can edit what I need but as soon as the focus is outside the input I can't edit it again If I need it. You get it?

Comment: yep you should be able to do it until you fill the field. After filled the input in this way, on blur, it will be disabled. But if you want to you can just add a `ng-click="dataValue.toDisable=false;"` in this line and you should achieve the edit when you click